# TIdHTTP character encoding of POST error response

Tags: delphi, post, decoding, indy10, idhttp

I'm using Delphi 7 with Indy 10.6.2.5459 to make a `POST` request to a server. It's all working fine, except for the response encoding when an `EIdHTTPProtocolException` occurs.

When I don't get `EIdHTTPProtocolException` raised, I can decode the response like this to properly get special characters:

```
responseBody := '';
responseContent := TStringStream.Create('');
try
  try
    IdHTTP.Post(GetUrlMetodo(ASngpcCloudRequest.Tipo), requestBody, responseContent);
    responseBody := UTF8Decode(responseContent.DataString);
  except
    on E: EIdHTTPProtocolException do
      responseBody := UTF8Decode(E.ErrorMessage);
  end;
finally
  FreeAndNil(responseContent);
end;
```

But, when an `EIdHTTPProtocolException` is raised, the `E.ErrorMessage` property has `?` instead of the expected special characters, even when using `UTF8Decode()`.

So, how can I properly decode the `E.ErrorMessage`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you are using Delphi 7, the native `string` type is `AnsiString`, which is important to note because it means Indy has to do more work when decoding strings.

When `TIdHTTP` parses an HTTP response body into a `string`, it is first decoded into Unicode using the response charset, as reported by the server.  If the server sends a response in UTF-8 encoding, for instance, it is required to specify that in the `charset` attribute of the `Content-Type` header.

In pre-Unicode versions of Delphi/FreePascal, that Unicode data is then converted to ANSI in order to fit in an `AnsiString`.  In those compiler versions, `TIdHTTP` methods which return a `string` have an optional `ADestEncoding` parameter to let you specify which `AnsiString` encoding you want the Unicode data converted to.  If not specified, Indy's default encoding is used, which is US-ASCII by default (see the global `GIdDefaultTextEncoding` variable in the `IdGlobal` unit).

You really should let Indy handle this decoding for you, since there is no guarantee that any given response with be UTF-8 encoded.  You can, however, specify that you want Indy's output to always be UTF-8 encoded (pre-Unicode versions only), eg:

```
try
  responseBody := UTF8Decode(
    IdHTTP.Post(GetUrlMetodo(ASngpcCloudRequest.Tipo), requestBody,
      IndyTextEncoding_UTF8)
  );
except
  on E: EIdHTTPProtocolException do
    responseBody := E.ErrorMessage;
end;
```

If you ever upgrade to a Unicode version of Delphi, you can then simply remove the extra UTF-8 step:

```
try
  responseBody := IdHTTP.Post(GetUrlMetodo(ASngpcCloudRequest.Tipo), requestBody);
except
  on E: EIdHTTPProtocolException do
    responseBody := E.ErrorMessage;
end;
```

In the example you provided in your question, you are bypassing `TIdHTTP`'s automated decoding logic, receiving the raw response body *as-is* into a `TStream` instead of a `string`.  In which case, you are then responsible for making sure you check the response's `charset` to know how to decode the raw data properly.  It may not always be UTF-8.  Indy has `ReadStringFromStream()` and `ReadStringAsCharset()` functions which allow you to specify an encoding/charset when reading a `string` from a `TStream`.

Now, to answer your question, why can't you decode the  `EIdHTTPProtocolException.ErrorMessage` correctly?  Well, because it has *already* been decoded by `TIdHTTP` for you.

*HOWEVER*, here is the rub - when decoding an error response to put into `EIdHTTPProtocolException`, the `ADestEncoding` parameter is NOT currently accessible from the code that is raising the exception, so Indy's default encoding gets used instead, and that is US-ASCII by default.  So that is why you are seeing "special" characters getting converted to `?` (again, this only affects pre-Unicode versions of Delphi/FreePascal).

You have a couple of options to work around this issue:

1. set the global `IdGlobal.GIdDefaultTextEncoding` variable to `encUTF8` before calling `Post()`.  This way, if `EIdHTTPProtocolException` is raised, its `ErrorMessage` will be UTF-8 encoded.  Note that this does affect Indy globally, and has much more influence in pre-Unicode versions of Delphi than in Unicode versions, so be careful with it.

   ```
   GIdDefaultTextEncoding := encUTF8;        
   ...
   try
     ...
     responseBody := ...;
   except
     on E: EIdHTTPProtocolException do
       responseBody := UTF8Decode(E.ErrorMessage);
   end;
   ```
2. since you are saving both success and failure responses to the same `responseBody` variable, you may as well just disable the use of `EIdHTTPProtocolException` altogether, and remove your `try/except` block.  You can do this by enabling the `hoNoProtocolErrorException` and `hoWantProtocolErrorContent` flags in the `TIdHTTP.HTTPOptions` property before calling `Post()`.  You can check the `TIdHTTP.ResponseCode` property to differentiate between success and failure responses:

   ```
   IdHTTP.HTTPOptions := IdHTTP.HTTPOptions + [hoNoProtocolErrorException, hoWantProtocolErrorContent];
   responseBody := UTF8Decode(
     IdHTTP.Post(GetUrlMetodo(ASngpcCloudRequest.Tipo), requestBody,
       IndyTextEncoding_UTF8)
   );
   ```

Comment: I used the first option and It worked. Thank you very much, I learned a lot with your answer.